# How to add custom file upload button in CKEditor with Cross domain support

Tags: file-upload, cross-domain, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in one of my web application. I am enabling the FileUpload option in CKEditor by setting `filebrowserImageUploadUrl` property.

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'http://MyServer.com/fileupload.ashx',
 });
```

Now the problem is the location where image has to be uploaded is present on another server and my web application is hosted on another server.

So whenever I tried to upload the image using Upload button, It get successfully uploaded but CKEditor unable to display. When I see in console, it is giving the cross-domain policy error.

So is there a way to allow the cross-domain in CKEditor File Upload plugin. 
I am also open to other alternatives for uploading the image to another server (if presents).

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the features of the [SimpleUploads](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/p/simpleuploads-plugin-for-ckeditor.html) plugin