# CKeditor cross origin server file browser

Tags: php, ckeditor, cross-domain-policy

i've create a custom server browser file for ckeditor , testing on localhost and its works fine, but when i put file server on different domain and choose an image , the browser block me and then throw an exception

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "<MyfileServer>" from accessing a frame with origin "<Mysite with ckeditor>". Protocols, domains, and ports must match`

Searched every where but the document is very hard to understand

Answer (score 1):

File server script and CKeditor must be on the same domain and port. This is a general security consideration to prevent XSS attacks and almost always a good idea.

If it's absolutely crucial to have them on different domains, then look for different Cross-site scripting techniques, one of them is [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). I wrote a [post](https://ruslanbes.com/devblog/2014/10/12/jquery-cross-site-scripting-tutorial-and-demo/) on that topic some time ago demonstrating different XSS solutions.

Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086678/how-to-add-custom-file-upload-button-in-ckeditor-with-cross-domain-support).